# Как вызвать меню под тулбаром?

Tags: android, toolbar

Как вызвать меню под тулбаром? как показано на рис.2. Сейчас меню вызывается как на рис.1 сразу с угла экрана и закрывает собой часть тулбара.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно добавить в тему вашего приложения такой стиль (именование можно взять свое):

```
<item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OverflowMenu</item>
```

и такой стиль:

```
<style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
        <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">5.0dp</item>
    </style>
```

также можно добавить фон чтобы белый на белом не сливался:

```
<item name="android:popupBackground">@color/teal_700</item>
```

и вот такое получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]